# Selenium: Erase cookies from different domains

Tags: java, internet-explorer, firefox, cookies, selenium

I am trying to implement some Selenium Test cases where I navigate from different domains. At the beginning of my test I wish all cookies to be erased from all the domains that I have worked.

I have only managed to erase cookies from the specific domain with deleteAllVisibleCookies command. But I need to erase cookies from another two domains that are not yet active. 
I am working in Eclipse implementing a JUnit 4 script. If you can help me to find a way to, at the very beginning, erase cookies from my selected domains, I would appreciate it.

I appreciate it if you can tell me how to erase the cookies from Firefox, IE and Chrome.

Any questions you need me to answer to help me out in this, just write!

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could use the getCookies method and iterate over and erase all from your "domains you've worked"

Here's an example in python, but same idea in java:

```
wd = self.webdriver
cookies = wd.get_cookies()
for cookie in cookies:
    if cookie["domain"] == [domains i've worked]:
       wd.delete_cookie(cookie["name"])
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and let you know how it worked for me :)